# In C#, how to create an array of data that's updating every 15 seconds

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm a programming student that is assigned a project where I have to use a random number representing a user selected unit of measurement and returning the measurement, the converted measurement, and the time collected.

I set up a dispatcher timer at an interval of 15 seconds for the timer. So how it works is the program triggers an event every 15 seconds that displays a random number in either a metric or English measurement, then displays the converted value and the time and of course, the timer starts with a start button and displays the data until a stop button is depressed.

My question is that I would like to show a limited history of the collected data, but I am having trouble with the array.  Each time it changes to a new data, it either writes over the previous data or doesn't add the new data, depending on how I formulate the statement. So when displaying to a label, it only shows one line of the current data, and not showing any other data.

For example, the user selects "centimeters" the program determines that it is metric and uses a random number as its value concatenated with the converted value and time value.

15 seconds later the event is triggered and a new random number is displayed for "centimeters".

So after combining the three values (measurement, converted measurement and time) which I'll call dataCollected, I populate the array:

```
    string [] dataHistory = new string[10]
    for (int i = 0; i < dataHistory.Length; i++)
    {
        if (dataHistory[i] == null || dataHistory[i] == "")
        {
            dataHistory[i] = dataTlt + "\n";
        }
    }
    foreach (string c in dataHistory)
    {
       collectedLbl.Content = c;
    }
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet really doesn't give enough information to go on; there could be multiple problems, but one problem you have at least is your `foreach` loop is simply replacing the content of your label with each iteration.  It would be better to use:

```
collectedLbl.Content = string.Join(", ", dataHistory);
```

(note - you don't need the `foreach` with this)

It's not clear to me that you're not also replacing the entire array with each event since the event handling isn't shown, but hopefully this helps get you further along.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (string c in dataHistory)
{
    collectedLbl.Content = c;
}
```

The problem here is you are setting the content of the label to each string in the dataHistory array. This is not an accumulating operation: each time you set this data you are overwriting the contents of the label. If you want the label to show all the values in that array you could do, for instance:

```
collectedLbl.Content = String.Join("\n", dataHistory);
```

This would join all the values in the array into a single string with new lines in between each element.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet doesn't show if these are all calls in a single function, but it appears that you are not re-using your `dataHistory` array, but are instead creating a new array each iteration.  If it is your intent to store the last 10 transactions, you need to initialize the array outside the function.  Also, this loop is still somewhat flawed, in that the 11th transaction wouldn't post to the array at all. (You have no method for removing the oldest item if all 10 array positions have data.)

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration, your first loop stores the result `dataTlt + "\n"` in **all** positions of the `dataHistory` array, and never remove the oldest result when reaching the limit of 10 in the history. It's easier if you just use a `List<string>` rather than an `string[]`:

```
List<string> dataHistory = new List<string>();
```

And now update as follows:

```
dataHistory.Add(dataTlt);

// remove first result if history has over 10 elements
if(dataHistory.Count > 10)
  dataHistory.RemoveAt(0);
// now, update your label
collectedLbl.Content = String.Join("\n", dataHistory);
```